# How can I enable the DevArt performance counters in Resource Monitor?

Tags: performancecounter, windows-server-2016, devart, resource-monitor

I'm using the [DevArt dotConnect for Oracle performance counters](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/PerformanceCounters.html) in my dev/test environment. By adding `Use Performance Monitor=True` to my database connection string, I can capture useful information such as number of connections, etc.

[image]

However, on my production box, I cannot see the DevArt performance counters in Resource Monitor:

[image]

I believe that the performance counters are installed, since they appear in the registry:

[image]

...and I imagine that adding `Use Performance Monitor=True` to my database connection string would cause an error if the relevant DLLs etc. were not present.

What else do I need to do to make the performance counters appear in Resource Monitor?

Comment: What is the difference between your developer and production environment?

Make sure you run the application for the first time with administrator rights. (It creates "Devart dotConnect for Oracle" counter section).

Make sure you still pass "Use Performance Monitor=True;" in the connection string on your production environment.

Comment: @Devart: when you say "*make sure you run the application for the first time with administrator rights*", what application are you referring to? The application I'm monitoring (a website)? Does this then install the performance counters globally? If so, can I run *another* application with a different user account (but still with admin rights) to get the counters installed, and then use them with my website (assuming I also modify the connection string for that application)?

Comment: Yes, it must be enough to run once another application with administrator rights, which opens Oracle Connection and contains "Use Performance Monitor=True;" in the connection string.

Comment: @Devart: I was finally able to arrange this on our production server (I created a dummy application that simply connects to the database with `Use Performance Monitor=True` in the connection string, and ran that application under my administrator account). It made no difference. Even after rebooting the server, the DevArt performance counters are still not available in Performance Monitor.

Comment: @Devart: Note that the counters appear to be set up in the registry at `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Devart dotConnect for Oracle\Performance` *but* they are not listed in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Perflib\009\Counter` (which they are on my Dev/Test box).

Comment: @Devart: what can I try next?

Comment: We still don't know: what is the difference between your developer and production environment? Typically the "Devart dotConnect for Oracle" Performance Counters shall appear after the first run of the application which opens Oracle Connection and contains "Use Performance Monitor=True;" in the connection string (and has necessary permissions). We don't see different behavior in our environment. Probably the problem does not apply to the connector itself and is related to some local settings in your production environment.